# Mysterious AJAX issue

Tags: jquery, json

### Update:

Ok, this isn't a problem with timeouts. I took out all the expensive parts of the PHP script, and made it just output `[1,2,3]`, so that it won't timeout. *Still doesn't work*, so clearly I'm doing something really braindead.

The whole thing:

```
sparql_url = "http://royiv.dyndns-ip.com/websci/git/clean_payroll_json.php";

function foo(response)
{
    alert("foo called.");
    alert(response);
    hers = response["DOE, JANE"];
    alert(hers);
}

function bar(request, stat, err)
{
    alert("Something messed up.");
    alert(err);
}

$.ajax({
    url: sparql_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: bar,
    success: foo,
    timeout: 20 * 1000
});
```

Output is "foo called", "null", and then the JS is terminated.

Viewing the transfer in Wirshark shows the response is sent. Firebug does not show anything in the "Response" tab, but shows a Content-Length of 7.

---

### The Original Question:

I'm having a weird timeout issue with jQuery. After 10 seconds, *something* is terminating the request, but I'm not sure what. As I watch the HTTP request in Wireshark, at just about 10 seconds, Firefox starts sending RST to the server, closing the connection. Here is how I'm performing the request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: sparql_url,
    error: bar,
    success: foo,
    timeout: 20 * 1000
});
```

After the timeout, `foo`, the **success** function, is being called, *not the error callback*. This makes me think jQuery isn't doing it, but I'm not sure here. What's going on here? (The URL is slow, but it is actually responding at just about 10 seconds. It is sending back JSON data.)

Comment: @Thanatos , open firebug  net panel and check whats happening there???

Comment: @gov: Firebug shows the request being made, but shows an empty response. Wireshark shows the response is being transmitted.

Comment: @thanatos , that means your backend is timing out right?? have you everseen data flowing from back to UI for that backend service?? is it something broken recently

Comment: @gov: English... please? The response *is* being transmitted, the backend is not timing out. (It's now sending a tiny static response.) Firebug shows no response, despite the fact that Wireshark shows it arriving.

Comment: @Tanatos , are you not able to follow my english??

Comment: @gov: No, not really. Could you clarify your response?

Comment: @Thanatos , to ruleout same origin policy , is your javascript file and the server file on the same website ??

Comment: Are you sure you're using `json_encode()` in php? This could be causing a type discrepancy.

Comment: @gov: No, they are not. My understanding was that jQuery could deal with that, and Wireshark seems to bear that assumption out: the HTTP request is made, I'm just not getting the right response back.

Comment: @Fred: I was using `json_encode` originally. The minimal example is just `echo "[1,2,3]";` The URL is included in the question, you can verify the correctness of the JSON if you want.

Comment: Could someone with more rights than me edit the F word out of the bar function please?

Comment: @Bernhard Hofmann: Oops, my mistake. Editted. :-) It's late at night here.

Answer (score 2):

In your phpscript set the "Content-Type" header to application/json instead of text/html.

Comment: This is a good thought - changed. No change in output, though, although the change in Content-type is reflected by Firebug and Wireshark. (But they disagree on response body.)

Comment: Is the page that does the ajax request and the script on the same domain? If not try this: http://dirolf.com/2007/06/enabling-cross-domain-ajax-in-firefox.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you inspect the response data with wireshark? If the response is empty, there is  something wrong with the php script. Maybe the php script produces an empty response if it is called by javascript (missing some http header like user agent, language, encoding, ...).

just a guess...

Comment: Not a bad guess, but Tjelle knows ajax better than me :-)

Comment: Wireshark shows that the response body is being transmitted. Verified the JSON by eye, but if it were invalid, jQuery should be calling the error handler.